# Activemq (JMS) with multiple tomcats

Tags: java, spring, jms, activemq-classic

Is it possible to produce a JMS event that will be consumed in a specific tomcat node? 
We are facing a problem that in our cluster of 3 tomcats - an event is thrown from one of the tomcats and is actually consumed by a different node even though we would like it to stick to the same tomcat (original)

Answer (score 1):

So, you share a broker between your Tomcat instances?

Fine, use separate topics/queues for each instance, maybe a prefix would be the easiest way.

You can also send the tomcat instance ID (or what have you) as a JMS String property with each message. Then on the consumer, you consume with a selector that filter the message based on the instance Id.